# Filtro de pesquisa com JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou fazendo um filtro de pesquisa com Vue.js e em meu filtro eu gostaria de pesquisar nome e email, mas apenas consegui fazer com o nome do usuario, como colocar mais um "argumento".

O codigo está assim

```
computed: {
    filteredUsers: function(){
      return this.userLists.filter((userList) => {
        return userList.usuario.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  },
```

Eu gostaria que fosse algo como

```
return userList.usuario.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || userList.email.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já esta na iteração do filtro então da para fazer o que você quer!
Sugiro trocar o nome da variável interna do filtro de userLists para outra como item, pois o que ele receber é cada item da sua this.userLists e colocar o mesmo nome gera confusão, mas de resto da para fazer o que você quer.

```
computed: {
    filteredUsers: function(){
      return this.userLists.filter((item) => {
        return (
                 item.usuario.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                 item.email.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
               );
      });
    }
  },
```